# jqGrid: URL to server side function?

Tags: php, url, jqgrid, xampp

I am trying to view a database table in browser with jqGrid, using XAMPP. Following the example at
http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid

```
$(function(){ 
  $("#list").jqGrid({
    url:'example.php',
    datatype: "json"
```

What kind of function is example.php? -"Typically this is a server-side function with a connection to a database which returns the appropriate information to be filled into the Body layer in the grid". Anyone has a standardized example of this function for Apache/PHP/Mysql solution?

Comment: The example is on the same page... did you try scrolling [down](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid#php_and_mysql_example_file)?

Comment: Aha! My bad, i thought example.php it would be an additional file..
thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 0):

example.php is a server side url which will have a database query to retrieve all the desired records and map it in a list which contains properties as defined in colmodel in the grid.